# return não encerra a execução da função

Tags: javascript, node.js

Teoricamente a função deveria retornar verdadeiro, mas retorna falso. Existe algo que estou fazendo errado?

```
    function main(num) {
      if (num > 10) {
        return true
      }
      return false
    }
    
    console.log(main(9))
```

Comment: O valor do argumento que está passando para a função é 9. 9 é menor que 10, então retorna `false`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

sua verificação da função é: "se o número inserido for maior que 10, retorne verdadeiro, se não, retorne falso"

agora veja quando você insere 9 na função: "se **9** for maior que **10**, retorne verdadeiro, se não, retorne falso"

sua função não está errada, apenas está se perdendo na verificação

Comment: Percebi isso depois que postei, mas não consegui apagar. Obrigado pela resposta, foi falta de atenção

Answer (score -2):

Para que a função retorne verdadeiro a condição seria de que o valor que está sendo passado por parâmetro seja MAIOR que 10 mas no seu exemplo está sendo passado um valor inferior ao mesmo, por isso que está sempre retornando false.

É só se atentar a condição do if, ali que está o "problema".